# a kind of IFRAME for Android app

Tags: android-layout

Is there any kind of iframe for android.?

I have an Ad spot in the bottom and the ads need to be visible on each activity page.

I already make an Activity class for my ad. The ad can be in mp4 or png format.

Comment: Do you mean "ad" as in "advertisement?" That's what [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a WebView:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: If I add a webview in my current LinearLayout and click by example on a button where I'm redirecting to an other activity class, I'll need to add the webview again. This is not a kind of IFRAME.

Comment: I Finally change the way I tried with the WebView Elements. Thanks